# Why doesn't %zd printf format work in VS2010?

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Following piece of my code does not print the value in visual studio.

```
int main() { 
    intptr_t P = 10;
    printf("test value is %zd",P);
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
test value is zd
```

I expect the the above code print

```
test value is 10
```

i am using intptr_t instead of integer so as to make the code to adjust in both the 32 bit and 64 bit architecture.

Comment: Please use a consistent indenting style. It will help both us and you read your code.

Comment: @bdonlan and Bart, Thanks for the suggestion and i am sorry for everything :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `z` prefix isn't defined in Microsoft's version of `printf`. I think the `I` prefix might work. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcxf1dw6.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Although the `z` length specifier is supported in C99, Visual Studio 2010 does not support C99, and instead conforms to an older version of C that was missing the `z` length specifier. As an extension, VS2010 does support the [`I` length specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcxf1dw6.aspx) instead for `size_t`, but this is not portable to other platforms.

I would recommend using an `unsigned long long` with the `%llu` specifier instead; the overhead is minimal and it's portable to C99 platforms as well.

Comment: The MS documentation doesn't allow `%llu` as an option, only `%lld`. And you'd want to cast the parameter to the proper size too.

Comment: @Mark Ransom would like to use **uintptr_t** as well for the unsigned intger. What do you suggest for me in this case?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9610747/which-c99-features-are-available-in-the-ms-visual-studio-compiler

Answer (score 2):

For portable code, `#include <inttypes.h>` and use `PRIdPTR` in your `printf` format string.

```
printf("test value is %" PRIdPTR, P);
```

The [Wikipedia page for inttypes.h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inttypes.h) has a link to a version of that file that will work with Visual C++, and would probably work with VS2010 as well (if Microsoft didn't add an inttypes.h).

`PRIdPTR` is for `intptr_t`, `PRIuPTR` is for `uintptr_t`.

Comment: Since inttypes.h is still not there in VS2012, [here's a current link to the implementation tom mentioned, now on code.google.com](https://code.google.com/p/msinttypes/)

Answer (score 1):

Visual C++, as of VS 2013, does not support %z. If you want future versions to support it then vote on this bug:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/806338/vc-printf-and-scanf-should-support-z

Comment: I believe that support for this was added to VS 2015.

Answer (score 0):

To print size_t you need to use **%Iu** in VS and %zu in gcc